# Musical in Nature

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, music

## What is the next song in the list?

---

- Pedal To The Medal
- Not Inside -- Outside
- The Final Countdown
- Every Rose Has Its Thorn
- .........

---

## The Puzzle

---

Within these dots, you shall find a magical, mystical, hidden message.  A (wo)man more focused on the music than these dots would have a jump start.  To determine what they mean, you must pay attention to whats already been played, for those songs hold the key.

[image: ???decimal???]

Some of these things are not like the others, 
watch what you do, or you might have your druthers.

---

## A Final Clue

---

too lag cof fee

---

## Hints?

---

> - The first four songs reveal what type of puzzle this is.
>   - Once you know what type of puzzle it is, the hyphenated endings will begin to make sense as there is a unique attribute to this puzzle that may not be immediately obvious.
>   - A small hint may be steganographically hidden for after you have halfway decoded the puzzle.
>   - Pay attention to the features of what comes before the hyphens ;)
>   - Yahtzee!!!

Comment: My first thought was braille, but I don't know what `..` means. :(

Comment: @IanMacDonald Wikipedia says it's a hyphen.

Comment: I put my fingers over these dots... but I cant feel anything. >:-|

Comment: Ooh f" is in on this. Should be cracked by tonight. ;)

Comment: @Varon try harder. I can feel them. XD

Comment: Reminds me of morse code

Comment: @all  Just curious how far anyone has gotten ;)

Comment: Has anyone figured out the "final clue"?  I've had no luck with it, myself, yet.

Comment: Do you guys want a hint? Or still thinking on it?

Comment: I hope enigma tag fits well...and I also removed the lateral thinking tag...however you know better than me. :)

Comment: That one is ok too. Limited to 5 tags. ;)

Comment: I would say they should both be there. @manshu

Comment: Added a hint!! ;)

Comment: Is an anagram solver useful for part of this, or am I looking in the wrong rabbit hole?

Comment: Wrong rabbit hole.  That one has a honey badger in it. ;) @Khale_Kitha

Comment: Ah - well at least he don't care.

Comment: Random thought: Pedal (Petal), Outside, Countdown, Rose - "He loves me, he loves me not"

Comment: @Khale_Kitha nice random thought. Let me know if it takes you anywhere?

Comment: Chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37023/musical-in-nature

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK so. Collaborative effort has paid off once again.

The answer is

> [Maxwell's Silver Hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_Silver_Hammer)

This was arrived at with the following logic:

**Original Puzzle:** *To determine what they mean, you must pay attention to whats already been played, for those songs hold the key.*

**Hint:** *The first four songs reveal what type of puzzle this is* and
*Once you know what type of puzzle it is, the hyphenated endings will begin to make sense as there is a unique attribute to this puzzle that may not be immediately obvious.*

> Using a single word from each song title, we can make the phrase ***[Pe[t]al[s] Outside the Rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petals_Around_the_Rose)***, which is a type of "hidden rule" puzzle, the actual rules of which are described in [Matt's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/29477/17250). Using this information, as well as the translation of the Braille provided in [the Community Wiki answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28767/17250), we can come to the list of values shown in Matt's answer.
>
>  As the aforementioned answer states, we can then translate the pairs of numbers into ASCII, giving us `PL4Y B34T 4BBY S1T3`. With a little creative assumption, we can expand this as "Play Beat[les'] Abb[e]y[ Road] S[ide]1T[rack] 3", which just *happens to be* "Maxwell's Silver Hammer", the "Tool-[Ag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver)-[Coffee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_House)" hinted at above.

Answer (score 14):

Not a solution, but here's a conversion of the image to text, to make this puzzle accessible to the blind. :)

Braille:

```
⠼⠁⠋⠉⠃⠉⠑⠋⠁⠤⠚ ⠼⠃⠃⠋⠙⠋⠁⠃⠃⠤⠚
⠼⠉⠉⠃⠙⠁⠋⠉⠉⠤⠁⠀⠼⠁⠃⠉⠋⠉⠉⠃⠁⠤⠚
⠼⠋⠙⠁⠉⠑⠃⠙⠋⠤⠁⠀⠼⠁⠙⠙⠃⠉⠋⠙⠁⠤⠚
⠼⠋⠑⠃⠃⠁⠙⠑⠋⠤⠚⠀⠼⠙⠁⠑⠉⠑⠋⠁⠙⠤⠁

⠼⠁⠋⠉⠑⠃⠙⠋⠁⠤⠚⠀⠼⠋⠃⠙⠉⠉⠉⠃⠋⠤⠚
⠼⠋⠁⠉⠑⠙⠃⠁⠋⠤⠁⠀⠼⠁⠙⠋⠙⠋⠉⠙⠁⠤⠁
⠼⠃⠙⠉⠉⠙⠉⠙⠃⠤⠁⠀⠼⠙⠙⠙⠃⠉⠙⠙⠙⠤⠚
⠼⠁⠁⠉⠉⠉⠉⠁⠁⠤⠚⠀⠼⠙⠃⠋⠑⠁⠃⠃⠙⠤⠚

⠼⠉⠙⠁⠃⠙⠉⠙⠉⠤⠁⠀⠼⠁⠁⠋⠙⠃⠉⠁⠁⠤⠚
⠼⠋⠋⠉⠃⠙⠑⠋⠋⠤⠚⠀⠼⠁⠉⠋⠙⠃⠉⠉⠁⠤⠚
⠼⠙⠃⠉⠉⠙⠉⠃⠙⠤⠚⠀⠼⠋⠁⠙⠉⠑⠃⠁⠋⠤⠚
⠼⠋⠑⠁⠃⠙⠃⠑⠋⠤⠚⠀⠼⠁⠉⠑⠃⠙⠉⠉⠁⠤⠁

⠼⠑⠁⠃⠋⠙⠋⠁⠑⠤⠚⠀⠼⠃⠃⠃⠉⠙⠉⠃⠃⠤⠁
⠼⠁⠋⠉⠙⠉⠃⠋⠁⠤⠚⠀⠼⠋⠃⠑⠉⠁⠑⠃⠋⠤⠁
⠼⠁⠉⠃⠑⠃⠋⠉⠁⠤⠚⠀⠼⠁⠃⠉⠙⠙⠉⠃⠁⠤⠚
⠼⠙⠋⠑⠃⠙⠉⠋⠙⠤⠁⠀⠼⠁⠃⠙⠋⠉⠙⠃⠁⠤⠁
```

Possible translation:

```
16323561-0 22646122-0
33241633-1 12363321-0
64135246-1 14423641-0
65221456-0 41535614-1

16352461-0 62433326-0
61354216-1 14646341-1
24334342-1 44423444-0
11333311-0 42651224-0

34124343-1 11642311-0
66324566-0 13642331-0
42334324-0 61435216-0
65124256-0 13524331-1

51264615-0 22234322-1
16343261-0 62531526-1
13252631-0 12344321-0
46524364-1 12463421-1
```

Comment: Nice work. I did the first chunk, but was too lazy to do it all. :) (also, shouldn't they all start with `#`?)

Comment: Well I've tried playing the numbers, but it wasn't anything recognizable.  I also tried actually converting the braille into the sheet music version of braille, but after getting through the first line I realized that it's either clearly not that, or it's 100% gibberish.  (More accidentals than notes, for example.)O

Comment: What do you figure the -0 and -1 signify? The only on/off things in written music (pedal markings et al.) seem like they'd require something more robust than whatever the 8-digit chunks represent

Comment: @question_asker I considered whether or not those lines may have designated importance, validity, or even octaves, but it didn't go anywhere, so far.  It's worth noting, however, if you remove the ⠼ from the beginning of each line, then they turn into purely a-g, with the dash being an `a` or a `j`.

Comment: I tried playing only the lines that had a `1` on them.  Sounds pretty, but still don't recognize anything.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I'm actually curious how that sounds. Might have to play it myself. :)

Comment: Everyone's noticed that the last two digits of every group are the reverse of the first two, right? Any idea what that means?

Comment: Yeah, Alconja (iirc) mentioned that in the chat room, the other day.  I haven't found anything useful from taking just the outside numbers, or the inside numbers, personally, just yet, though.

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/Music_technology/midi/midi_note_numbers_for_octaves.htm

Midi numbers for different notes. The first line marked with a 1 is ACEA, for example. Let me know if I'm moving in the right direction?

Comment: I fixed a couple of errors (lines 9 and 14) of the braille transcription from image to text, and updated the resulting translation.

Comment: One thing that stands out is that the “music” uses a six-character alphabet instead of the traditional seven.

Answer (score 7):

**NOT THERE YET...**

In the chat room, I've been working with @Khale_Kitha and @question_asker to get a little further.

Turns out the translated braille is this type of puzzle:

> [Petals Around the Rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petals_Around_the_Rose) - Numbers 1 - 6 represent faces of a 6-sized die. Petals are counted as non-center pips when there exists a centered pip. The only numbers that have these are 3 (2 "petals") and 5 (4 "petals")

With this information we computed the translation like so:

> Counting 1, 2, 4 and 6 as 0, 3 as 2 and 5 as 4, we sum each sequence.
> 16323561 becomes 0 + 0 + 2 + 0 + 2 + 4 + 0 + 0 = 8, and so on for each sequence.

What of the hyphens?

> Well, adding 2s and 4s can result in any even number. We took it to mean subtraction, so where there is -1, we subtract 1 from the sum. Likewise, for -0, we subtract 0. This resulted in all the calculations representing numbers from 0 - 9, as such: 
>  8 0 
>  7 6 
>  5 2 
>  8 9 
>  
>  6 6 
>  5 1 
>  5 2 
>  8 4 
>  
>  5 2 
>  6 6 
>  6 6 
>  8 9 
>  
>  8 3 
>  4 9 
>  8 4 
>  5 1

Neat. We proceeded to translate that:

> Using each line as a decimal representation of an ASCII character, we got: 
>  `PL4Y B34T 4BBY S1T3`

From there we started making some guesses, but this is where we started getting stuck:

> Is that referencing The Beatles' Abbey Road? Abbey Someone? Why are only the vowels represented by numbers? What of the hint "too lag cof fee"?

Comment: You give me way too much credit by even mentioning my name here

Comment: Play the Beatles on the Abbey Road site? (Abbey road.com)

Comment: Yeah, we considered that, as well as a number of B-Side tracks to related Beetles songs (which all, incidentally, ended up being on the Abbey Road album)

Comment: Perhaps the hint is hexadecimal, like `700 1a9 c0f fee`.  That doesn't mean anything to me, though.

Comment: @dan04 You're right, but it was a new thought, at least.  I don't think we'd considered that. -- Though I think it'd be `700 1a6 c0f fee`